# how to pass list values to a single param function at oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that returns a list of person_id

```
select person_id from per_all_people_f .
```

and i have another function that takes person_id as a parameter.

```
package1.get_person_company(p_person_id)
```

what i want to do is to get the result as

```
person_id,get_person_company_result
```

so the function is invoked with all returned values from the first query.
how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the function for each row:

```sql
SELECT person_id,
       package1.get_person_company(p_person_id => person_id)
         AS get_person_company_result
FROM   per_all_people_f
```

Comment: it worked as expected !,but never seen this syntax before,
can you tell me the topic name please?

Comment: You are just calling a user-defined function from an SQL statement; it is reasonably basic functionality equivalent to calling a built-in function like `TO_CHAR` or `UPPER`.

Comment: i meant to say the arrow =>

Comment: It is just passing the value to a named parameter rather than passing the value by the position of the parameter. You don't need to use the `p_person_id =>` and can pass the parameters in order (rather than by name) if you want; like this `package1.get_person_company(person_id)`.